# Call a WebMethod which is in Custom Control(Not User Control) through Jquery Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a scenario where I have to use custom control (Textbox) in multiple Asp.net applications.

After adding the reference of custom control in application, I want to make a Ajax call on `Onblur` event of Custom Textbox which should call the Web Method which is in the Custom Control Class.

What excatly I have to do.

1st: Add a reference of Custom Control in Asp.net Apllication.
2nd: Onblur event of Custom Control Textbox calls a js file which contains the $.ajax method of Jquery.
3rd: $.ajax should make a call to the WebMethod which is in Custom Control class.

Comment: The url should be "...ctl.ascx/mywebmethod", however ascx files are not served by asp.net, so you have to put the method in another page

Comment: Im not using User Control (ascx). Im talking about Custom Control....

Comment: Sorry my mistake, however the same stands for custom control. If this file is not served by asp.net then you can't do it. You can do it maybe with http handler but for simplicity just put it in an aspx page. From the page you can call your control. Anyway, this is a static method.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it other than what Amiram Korach has suggested??